# What should be a good ratio between vitality and the main stat on Inferno?

Tags: diablo-iii

What should be a good main stat (for instance STR for Barb) and my vitality stat for survival?

What should be the ideal ratio I have to survive? I'm on hell at the moment with a 1:1 ratio and getting destroyed.

Comment: This is a very open ended question, because it is completely based on your skill choices, lifesteal, team composition and many other factors. If you were playing solo it would be much different than if you were playing with a group.

Comment: IMHO this question is too broad, I would suggest rework it targeting barbarian only, if your are interested in this class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its very hard to define "the optimum ratio", because really, its a personal choice, and the ratio is irrelevant if you don't have enough stats in the first place. Some players might prefer to be less squishy at the cost of less dps, while other players might decide they'd rather be able to kill mobs faster so there's less time for them to take damage.

Based on [this guide for Barbarians looking to farm Act 1 Inferno](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4210125663), you'd want about 1.2k vitality and 1.2k strength to reliably handle the start of Inferno. Of course, this would vary depending on your skill level and latency, not to mention all the other stats you have to worry about.

[Here's another post](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5149542120) by someone having difficulties on Inferno with their Barbarian, suggesting the same 30k-40k HP. Its suggested there to keep a roughly 1:1 ratio of vit:str. Resist gear is also vitally important in Inferno.

Don't worry too much about the ratio, and focus more on finding better gear with more points in stats that are useful. That said, if you feel like you're getting one shot, it makes sense to prioritise vitality , armour, dodge, and resists.